# Upload contacts from Nokia to LG Optimus L5: phone numbers in notes field

Tags: contacts, import

I have exported contacts from Nokia to CSV and TXT files and upload to gmail contacts then I set LG to sync gmail contacts.

It worked but all contacts are in comments.

I can't call when I select contact and when someone calls me I do not see contact name.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Are the contacts right in GMail?

Comment: No. All phone numbers are in comments box on the right. Phone number field is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had manually exported contacts to Google CSV, uploaded to Google Spreadsheets.
Edited manually table by copying comments column to phone number column, deleted extra text, upload CSV to contacts again